# Conversion to mathematical writing

Tags: logic

i was wrong on this question from uni, and i don't understand why both statements are wrong.

(The question isn't written in english, so i'll try my best to translate correctly. sorry.)

Statement: "In an open section (0,1) There isn't a maximal number. can be written as such:

1. $∀x∃y((x>0)∧(x < y)∧(y<1))$
2. $∀x((x<1)∧(x>0)→ ∃y(x<y))$

i knew the second one was wrong because there's no limit to the value of Y so it can go beyond 1

but why is the first one wrong?

x has to be higher than 0 and lower than 1 and lower than Y and Y has to be lower than 1. i don't get it.

someone mind explaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement translates roughly to:

> For all $x$, there exists a $y$ such that the following are true:
>
> - $x>0$
> - $x<y$
> - $y<1$

Now if we look at just the first point, we get "For all $x$, [$\cdots$] $x>0$."

This is clearly false, since $x$ can in fact be less than 0.

A similar statement that is equivelant to the given sentence is

$\forall x[(x>0)\to\exists y[(x<y)\land(y<1)]]$

Note that one of the AND's has been replaced by an "implies", and the existential quantifier has been moved inside.

Comment: so basically, $x$ can be higher than 1 and lower than 0
and the statement should take that into consideration and only apply itself if $x$ is between 0,1? I'm asking because "$x$ could be in fact less than 0." but it can be higher than 0 as well?

also, in the similar statement you wrote, $x$ needs to be <1 as well before the "implies" sign, doesn't it?

Comment: @YoadCahalonX yes. When you write "$\forall x$", you are saying "this is true for all possible values of $x$. So when you try to break down the no-maximum statement, you end up with something like, "For all numbers $x$, if $x$ is greater than 0, then there is a number $y$ that is greater than $x$ and less than 1.

Comment: As a side note (as you'll probably learn soon if you're in a class about this), it's common to replace $\forall x[x>0 \to P(x)]$ with $\forall x>0[P(x)]$. This new notation translates roughly to "For all $x$ that are greater than 0, $P(x)$ is true." This is called a domain restriction, and is usually a little bit easier to think about when translating from english/non-math-ese. Just remember that those two sentences are equivelant.